# Any way to keep apache proxy from timing out?

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I can't find in the docs if it's possible to keep apache from timing out on a proxy request. I'm trying to setup a socket server and am looking for this as an option.

Comment: You don't want to do that exactly, it will tie up an Apache thread possibly indefinitely. What you want to do is raise the timeout value.

Comment: correct. I changed my app arch to avoid this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try ProxyTimeout directive, and set it to a relatively big number in seconds as specified in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout

Comment: I changed the architecture of my app so I don't need to do this anymore, but I'll accept your answer =)